# Table Views with plists

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I have a plist with the structure:

```
Root - Dictionary
    Notes - Array 
        Item 0 - Dictionary
            Title - String
            Text - String
            Date - String
```

I am then doing:

...

```
NSString *noteTitle;
NSString *noteText;
NSString *noteDate;

self.notes = [self.data objectForKey:@"Notes"];
```

And configure the cell like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Title"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[self.notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Date"];
```

How do I then, in a button, add the noteTitle to the "Title" value in the plist?

```
[self.notes addObject:noteTitle];
```

Comment: You mean you want to edit the original plist when a button is tapped?

Comment: when the button is tapped i want to add the NSString *noteTitle to the "Title" key in the plist

Comment: Give details of the button. How are you loading the plist (are the dictionaries mutable). What have you tried? What did it do wrong?

Comment: The button is a button in an alert view that contains an edit field. The dictionaries are mutable. I have tried using self.notesData = [self.data initWithObjectsAndKeys:noteTitle, @"Title",noteText, @"Text",noteDate, @"Date", nil];

Comment: When I set the items in the Notes array to strings instead of dictionary, I can add the title of the note to the array using [self.notes addObject:noteTitle]; in the buttton just fine. But i need it to be a dictionary so I can add text and date to the noteData

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the alert is shown you need to know the index of the table you're editing so you know what index to edit when the button is tapped (`row` below). Then, you'll be doing something like:

```
[[self.notes objectAtIndex:row] setObject:noteTitle forKey:@"Title"];
```

---

If you really want to add a whole new item then you should be creating a new mutable dictionary, adding `noteTitle` to it and then adding that dictionary to `self.notes` (in which case you don't need the `row`).

```
NSDictionary *d = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:noteTitle, @"Title",noteText, @"Text",noteDate, @"Date", nil];
[self.notes addObject:d];
```

Comment: Note that when you read plists into memory, all the objects that are read are read as immutable objects. If you want to use code like the above, you have to convert the objects to their mutable form. That can be tricky if you have a nested structure like an array of dictionaries. You have to create a mutable array, then walk through the original array, making a mutable copy of each dictionary entry and saving it to the new mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fold 2 strings:

```
NSString *newString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",oneString,secondString];
```